# Date and time format in Android

Tags: android

How do you format correctly according to the device configuration a date and time when having year, month, day, hour and minute? for example I want to display 29 July, 2015, 10:30 Am, according to my time zone

Comment: You can have a look on the stack overflow question [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058880/date-and-time-formatting-depending-on-locale

Comment: @abdul Please check the below solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method to format the datetime... u can replace new java.util.Date() with any datetime variable...

```
 android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
 df.format("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm aa", new java.util.Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String strDateTime = "29 July, 2015, 10:30 Am";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy, hh:mm a");
strDateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
holder.txtTime.setText(strDateTime);
```

Please integrate the above code, that works fine for me.

Any help, do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Find the below solution**

```
Calendar ci = Calendar.getInstance();
 String AM_PM;

  if(ci.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==0)
    {
         AM_PM ="AM";
    }
    else
    {
         AM_PM ="PM";
    }
    String CiDateTime = "" +  ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+" "+
                              (ci.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)+","+
                               ci.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + 
       + "," +getCurrentTime()
       +" "+AM_PM;
```

**Call the method**

```
private String getCurrentTime()
{
  int hrsRight = 0;
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  int hrs = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
  int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  if (hrs>12) 
  {
   hrsRight = hrs - 12;
  }
  else
 {
 hrsRight = hrs;
 }
  return String.valueOf(hrsRight)+":"+String.valueOf(min);
 }
```