# Android - format time (hour and minutes) to specific locale (12h05, 12u05.. etc)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, datetime-format, time-format

I want to format a certain time/date,(HH:mm) to a specific locale type.
For example, I have 12:05 and I need it to be
- in french 12h05
- in dutch 12u05

Is this possible without checking the current locale and adjust the result?

```
fun String.hourFormat() : String {
       val time = LocalTime.parse (this, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
       val result = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm").withLocale(LocaleManager.currentLocale())
       return result
     }
```

Does there exist something already implemented to format the time based on locale?
The current approach for me is to manually check the locale :

```
   fun String.hourFormat() : String {
....
val localePattern = when (LocaleManager.currentLocale().name){
                       "FR" -> "HH'h'mm"
                       "NL" -> "HH'u'mm" 
                   }
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(localePattern)

}
```

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39992733/295004

Comment: [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedTime(java.time.format.FormatStyle))